# Triangle inequality of Dirichlet cofficients of Artin L-function.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

As for automorphic L-function we know that
$$
\left|\lambda_{\pi}(n)\right|^{2} \leq \lambda_{\pi \times \widetilde\pi}(n)
$$
is there exist a inequality similarly for Artin L-functions?

For above inequality we can refer the Appendix in Weak subconvexity without a Ramanujan hypothesis by K Soundararajan and J Thorner.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert on these things, but for Artin L-functions, we know the Ramanujan conjectures: any Artin representation $\rho\colon G_{\mathbb Q}\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ has finite image, so the eigenvalues of any element are roots of unity. Since the goal of Soundararajan--Thorner is to prove such a result *without* the Ramanujan conjectures....

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I made a mistake, I mean $
\left|\lambda_{\pi}(n)\right|^{2} \leq \lambda_{\pi \times \widetilde\pi}(n)
$.

Comment: Why has this been closed? This is a perfectly valid question that is understandable to number theorists.

Comment: @PeterHumphries : The post was closed as missing context. To the OP: please consider adding some background material (say, the definition of Artin L-function), and what kinds of similar inequality are you expecting.

Comment: Tangentially related recent meta discussion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/non-experts-closing-questions)

Comment: @ArcticChar I don't understand the need for the OP to define Artin $L$-functions. These are well-understood to algebraic number theorists (they have their own Wikipedia page). The analogous inequality is also obvious (replace $\pi$ with $\rho$). It seems the people who voted to close do not work in algebraic number theory, so I don't understand their overzealous moderating. If you don't know an area well, why would you moderate it??

Comment: Well, I don't disagree with you. But as you see in the meta thread I linked above, there are lots of argument there (which I don't think we need to repeat here). Pragmatically, the easiest way to get this reopened is to add some context to it, so that other users are willing to vote to reopen. @PeterHumphries

Comment: @PeterHumphries (at the unramified primes) is it an inequality that holds for all Euler product $\prod_p 1/f_p(p^{-s})$ with $f_p(0)=1$ and the roots of $f_p$ on the unit circle? If so then I didn't see the trick for comparing the coefficients of the LHS and RHS and I would be happy to see at least a sketch of it (like induction on $\deg f_p$).